# How to multiply some elements of a variable by a constant, depending on the value of another variable, in every data frame of a list of data frames

Tags: r

I have a list of 100 data frames, each corresponding to one participant, in which there is a variable "trial" (100 trials), a variable "response" (0/1 for incorrect/correct) and a variable "time" (for reaction times). Here is an example of my data:

```
library(tidyverse)
# list of data sets
my_responses <- tibble(participant = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), trial1 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), trial2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), trial3 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1))
my_times <- tibble(participant = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), rt1 = c(0.5, 1.1, 1.3, 0.4, 0.6, 1.2, 1.9, 0.6, 0.8), rt2 = c(0.8, 0.7, 1.4, 1.5, 0.6, 1.3, 0.9, 0.8, 1.2), rt3 = c(0.4, 0.9, 1.3, 1.1, 1.6, 0.3, 0.9, 1.4, 1.3))
my_responses <- my_responses %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(2:ncol(my_responses)), names_to = "trials1", values_to = "response")
my_times <- my_times %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(2:ncol(my_times)), names_to = "trials2", values_to = "times")
my_data <- my_responses %>% bind_cols(my_times)
my_data <- my_data %>% subset(select = -c(participant...4, trials2))
my_data <- split(my_data, f = my_data$participant...1)
```

Now I need to give a negative sign to the incorrect responses. So, for each data frame in my list I need to multiply the variable "time" by -1 if the variable "response" has the value 0.

I've tried several things, based on previous answers to questions here, but none seem to be working. Here is what I tried so far:

1)

```
# multiply times of incorrect responses (0) by -1
my_data <- lapply(my_data, function(x) {ifelse(my_data[[x]]$response == 0, my_data[[x]]$times*-1, my_data[[x]]$times*1)})
```

which gives the error: Error in my_data[[x]] : invalid subscript type 'list'

2)

```
my_data <- lapply(my_data, function(x) {ifelse(my_data$response == 0, my_data$times*-1, my_data$times*1)})
```

which gives me just a list with 9 elements with the value logi(0)

3)

```
my_data <- lapply(names(my_data), function(x) {ifelse(my_data[[x]]$response == 0, my_data[[x]]$times*-1, my_data[[x]]$times*1)})
```

which gives me a list with 9 elements, each with the "times" multiplied by -1 or not according to variable "response". This seems to be close but I need the output to be again a list of data frames (the same I had).

I appreciate any help to try to make this work!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try this:

```r
for (i in 1:length(my_data)) {
    my_data[[i]] <- my_data[[i]] %>% mutate(times = ifelse(response, times, -times))
}
```